# How to install firmware without internet connection (debian 9 live)

Tags: debian, wifi, internet, firmware

I am using a debian stretch live i386 gnome iso image with non-free firmware that I have booted from my usb, and I can find my wifi network but I am unable to connect after entering my password.  There is nothing wrong with the password or router, as I was able to login and use wifi from this pc.  I do not have an ethernet cable, so I have no internet connection on debian and therefore cannot install the necessary firmware via sources.list (let me know if there is a way to do this w/o internet though).

Is there a way for me to download the necessary firmware onto my usb from Microsoft Windows?  My wifi driver is RT3572, and I am using a Lenovo Ideapad 100S with an intel processor.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

If I need to, I will just go out and get an ethernet cable.